# Как вывести из потока сообщение на textView?

Tags: java, android, textview

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой в своем приложении. Имеется сервер с использованием ServerSocket. В котором есть небольшой UI с тремя JTextField и JButton. В которых я заполняю информацию и по нажатию кнопки отправляю информацию на клиент, который написан под Andoid.
Проблема в следующем, я не разбираюсь как работают потоки в Android пока приложение работает. И как только я отправляю сообщение на клиент textView сразу же им не заполняется. Приложение начинает подлагивать и как только я тыкну в какой-то виджет оно вроде разлагивает и только тогда выводит собщение на textView. Как только я что то посылаю с сервера в log Android Studio выводится следующее сообщение

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Допустим у меня на активности есть Button "отправить" и EditText. Так вот после того как с сервера я присылаю сообщение на клиент, открываю его и ставлю фокус на EditText нажатием на него он начинает лагать, как только я еще раз клацну на него, чтобы он полностью открылся приложение разлагивает и на textView только тогда выводится сообщение с сервера. Так же при повторной отправке сообщения с сервера, textView не обновляется, возможно причина связана с тем, что код находится в функции onCreate();

В чем же может быть проблема и как с ней бороться ?

```
public class Server{

private static BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
JFrame frame;
JButton sendButton;
JPanel panel;
JTextField nameTextField, serviceTextField, percentTextField;


public Server(){
    frame = new JFrame("AutoRate discount");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(410,100);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    sendButton =  new JButton("Send discount");
    nameTextField = new JTextField(10);
    serviceTextField = new JTextField(10);
    percentTextField = new JTextField(10);
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(nameTextField);
    panel.add(serviceTextField);
    panel.add(percentTextField);
    panel.add(sendButton);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    sendButton.addActionListener(new MyListener());
}

private static final int portNumber = 60123;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Server server  = new Server();
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    try{

        System.out.println("Server started at port number " + portNumber);
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);

        // Waiting for client connection
        System.out.println("Waiting for client connection");
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("A client has connected");

        // Send message to the client
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        //String s = server.nameTextField.getText() + server.serviceTextField.getText() + server.percentTextField;
        //bufferedWriter.write(s);


        // Receive message from client
        String data;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        while((data = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println("Message from client " + data);
        System.out.println("Server has ended");


    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Обработчик нажатия кнопки
private class MyListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String s = nameTextField.getText() + serviceTextField.getText() + percentTextField.getText();
        try {
            bufferedWriter.write(s);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            bufferedWriter.flush();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Клиентский код:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Socket socket = null;
public String debuggingString = "DEBUG";
// We should use here Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1: IpV4
public String hostname = "192.168.253.1"; // <-- paste your IPv4 here
public int portNumber = 60123;
TextView textView;
BufferedReader bufferedReader;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                //connecting
                Log.e(debuggingString, "Attempting to connect to server");
                socket = new Socket(hostname, portNumber);

                //Send message to server
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                bw.write("this is a message from the client");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();

                //Receive message from server
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                textView.setText(bufferedReader.readLine());
            } catch (
                    Exception e
                    )
            {
                Log.e(debuggingString, e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем приложении используются потоки данных - и все запросы происходят в основном UI потоке, отчего и появляются подлагивания.

Ошибка, которая вам выводится говорит о том, что лишь главный поток может обращаться к этому виджету.

> Проблема в следующем, я не разбираюсь как работают потоки в Android пока приложение работает.

Из сказанного выше вам нужно понять - что у вас потоки данных, а не параллельные потоки.

Есть множество способов распараллелить потоки, почитайте про [многопоточность в android](https://habrahabr.ru/company/eastbanctech/blog/192998/)

UDP:  [подобный вопрос уже задавался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533429/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80)